# jqgrid - initial filter value not properly set when using searchoptions with dataUrl

Tags: search, jqgrid, data-url

I think this is a bug in jqGrid (I'm using version 4.4.0). In my colModel, this works fine:

```
stype:'select', searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq','ne'], value:"Red:Red;Green:Green;Blue:Blue"}
```

but this does not:

```
stype:'select', searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq','ne'], dataUrl:'rest/selectcolors'};
```

where the dataUrl is returning

```
<option value='Red'>Red</option><option value='Green'>Green</option><option value='Blue'>Blue</option></select>
```

The colors show up okay in the combobox with 'Red' as the default value but the filter is not correctly initialized unless the user changes the combobox filter by selecting 'Green' or 'Blue' (and then possibly going back and selecting 'Red'). If the user tries to filter without first changing the combobox value, no matches are found. This problem occurs upon initial use of the filter dialog and after resetting the filter dialog, so it is very confusing to the user.

Does anyone know of a workaround / fix for this?

Comment: Further testing shows that the problem occurs when the 'select' search is the first search option in the search dialog; i.e. when the user Resets the search dialog, the Color search option is displayed. Thus after a reset, the search dialog shows "Color  equals  Red" but clicking Find returns no matching results and the value of $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData').filters is {"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"color","op":"eq","data":""}]} (note that data property is the empty string instead of "Red").

Answer (score 0):

in first sight your returned dataurl doesn't have

```
<select>
```

and it might be a mistake

however, i have this problem too!
but i don't find any solution by search on web.
i resolve this problem temporary by a trick
i add one option with value = -1 and text "Please Select"
then in change event i remove this option

```
searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq', 'ne'], dataUrl:'yoururl',              
                dataEvents:[{ type: 'change',
                        fn: function(e) 
                            {                    
                                $('td.data').find('option[value=-1]').remove();                                 
                            }                                
                }]},
```

but the problem still exist.. if user doesn't change combobox and select "Please Select" option, he will see an error.

i use the folowing code in my php url

```
echo "<select>";    
echo "<option value='-1'>please select</option>";     
while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($res)) 
{                        
    echo "<option value='".$row['cid']."' >".$row['cname']."</option>";                    
}    
echo"</select>";
```

you can use an style like this and remove it after change for select element

> style='font-style:italic; color:gray; width:100px' data-native-menu='false'