# jqgrid sending empty ("")value with stype:'select' and searchoptions:{dataUrl:...} if user submits the search form without changing the selected value

Tags: jquery, search, jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid with some column like this:

```
{label:'test',
name:'dn',
index:'dn_id',
sortable:false,
align:'center',
editable:false,
search:true,stype:'select',
searchoptions:{
    sopt: ['eq'],
    defaultValue:'1000',
    dataUrl:'<?php echo URL::base().'reports_dn/get_dns';?>'}
}
```

the select dropdown is created successfully from dataUrl. but if user selects search and presses submit button without changing the current dropdown selection, empty value is sent to server for 'dn_id'. but if I change the drop down selected value, it works correctly. it seems like a bug but I'm not sure about it. please help.
thanx

Comment: Which browser are you using? I have a similar issue with ie8

Answer (score 0):

i have this problem too! but i don't find any solution by search on web. i resolve this problem temporary by a trick i add one option with value = -1 and text "Please Select" then in change event i remove this option.

please see it

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17526140/2527458

it maybe help u